# What is the area of the ABCD rectangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, area, education

[image]

$(1) \quad \dfrac{256}{17}$

$(2) \quad \dfrac{39}{4}$

$(3) \quad \dfrac{483}{8}$

$(4) \quad \dfrac{52}{4}$

$(5) \quad \dfrac{492}{18}$

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to know. The triangle could be drawn at any angle, giving different bounding box rectangles.

Comment: The triangle is not unique. However, the area of rectangle is bounded between $12$ and $16$. So only the first or fourth answer is possible.

Comment: Interesting problem, but if you want your question to remain open, please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your work accordingly. It's not just 'include your work' on there.

Answer (score 2):

Let $AE=a$, $BE=b$, $AF=c$, $DF=d$.

Now

\begin{align}
  a^2+c^2 &= 3^2 \tag{1} \\
  d^2+(a+b)^2 &= 4^2 \tag{2} \\
  b^2+(c+d)^2 &= 5^2 \tag{3} \\
  a^2+c^2+d^2+(a+b)^2 &= b^2+(c+d)^2 \tag{$3^2+4^2=5^2$} \\
  a(a+b) &= cd \tag{4} \\
  d^2+\left( \frac{cd}{a} \right)^2 &= 4^2 \\
  d^2(a^2+c^2) &= 4^2 a^2 \\
  3^2d^2 &= 4^2a^2 \\
  d &= \frac{4a}{3} \\
  c &= \sqrt{3^2-a^2} \\
  a+b &= \frac{4c}{3} \\
  (a+b)(c+d) &= \frac{4}{3} \sqrt{3^2-a^2}
  \left(
    \frac{4a}{3}+\sqrt{3^2-a^2}
  \right) \\
\end{align}

Unless $a+b=c+d$, that is a square, you cannot have a proper choice.

For the square case,

$$(a+b)(c+d)=\frac{256}{17}$$

I'm leaving the missing steps for above result as an exercise.

Comment: If you are going to post an answer, it would be better to post an incomplete solution since the OP hasn't shown any work yet.

Comment: This is a problematic problem, it's normal for most people unable to solve it.  That's an exceptional case.  Also, I leave the special case as an exercise.

Comment: It seems likely that the missing information is that the triangle is inscribed in a square, since this gives one of the choices.

Comment: It took me a while to realize you meant "if" when you wrote "unless".

Answer (score 2):

[image]

A unique triangle cannot be constructed so no area can be associated with it.

Shown here are two cases of rectangles (red and blue borders). The circles have radii $(5,4)$ for side lengths and a side of tangent length $3$ units between them.

EDIT1:

Area is not invariant. To calculate when hypotenuse makes an angle $u$ to vertical,

$$ (3 \cos u + 4 \sin u)(3 \sin u + +4 \cos u)=(12+12.5 \sin2u) $$

It has maximum value 24.5 when hypotenuse makes $45^{\circ}$ to vertical,  and minimum 12 at time of vertical/horizontal positions of the shorter sides.

Comment: True. The next question would be: is the area an invariant?

Comment: Please ask that in another question.

Comment: It's not my post, I'm just reacting.

Comment: The rigid yellow triangle triangle has constant area 6 sq. units..but  let me formulate

Comment: No. when hypotenuse makes $ 45^0$ to vertical,the area is maximum at 24.5; and minimum 12 at time of vertical/horizontal  positions of the shorter sides. Generally the area is  $ (12 +12.5 \sin 2u) $.

Comment: @cvanaret If another answer of mine is correct, it's unlikely the area to be invariant.

Comment: It is definitely not invariant. I have mentioned in the above comment how it varies.